# Parsing HTML with XPath and PHP

Tags: php, regex, xpath, html-parsing

Is there a way (using XPath and PHP) to do the following (WITHOUT external XSLT files)?

- Remove all tables and their contents
- Remove everything after the first h1 tag
- Keep only paragraphs (INCLUDING their inner HTML (links, lists, etc))

I received an XSLT answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571674/help-with-php-and-xpath), but I'm looking for XPATH queries that don't require external files.

Currently, I've got the HTML in question loaded into a SimpleXmlElement via:

```
$doc = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml);
$data = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
```

Now I need help with:

```
$data = $data->xpath('??????');
```

Been working with this one for several days to no avail.  I really appreciate the help.

Edit: **I don't particularly care what's inside the paragraphs, as I can use strip_tags to eliminate what I don't want.  All I need to do is to isolate the paragraphs from the rest of the source.  I suppose a more specific, accurate requirement would be this:**

**Return only paragraphs (and their html contents) that aren't contained in tables, and only before the first h1 tag**

Edit 2:

I think I've gotten most of it with this:
    `$query = $xpath->query('//p[not(ancestor::table) and not(preceding::h2)]');`

The only problem is the loss of the inner HTML.

Comment: Based on your assumption, is it alright to say `you just need <p>, including table inside a p`?

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: But I do not want any paragraphs that are inside tables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To just get all the P elements not within a table and only before the first h1, you can do

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$expression = '//p[not(preceding::h1[1]) and not(ancestor::table)]';
foreach ($xp->query($expression) as $node) {
    echo $dom->saveXml($node);
}
```

[Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/EuFAX3cw)

In general, if you know the position of the first h1 in the document, it is more performant to use a direct path to that element, instead of the `//` query which would search anywhere in the document. For instance, as an alternative you could also use the XPath given by Alejandro in the comments below:

```
/descendant::h1[1]/preceding::p[not(ancestor::table)]
```

---

If you want to create a new DOM Document from the nodes in the source document, you have to import the nodes into a new document.

```
// src document
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

// dest document
$new = new DOMDocument;
$new->formatOutput = TRUE;

// xpath setup
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$expr = '//p[not(preceding::h1[1]) and not(ancestor::table)]';

// importing nodes into dest document
foreach ($xp->query($expr) as $node) {
    $new->appendChild($new->importNode($node, TRUE));
}

// output dest document
echo $new->saveXML();
```

[Demo on codepad](http://codepad.org/0hFr6i9v)

---

**Some more additions**

In your example, you used the error suppression operator. This is bad practise. If you want to disregard any parsing errors from DOM, use

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // catch any DOM errors with libxml
$dom = new DOMDocument;           // remove the @ as it is bad practise
$dom->loadXML($xhtml);            // use loadHTML if it's not valid XHTML
libxml_clear_errors();            // disregards any DOM related errors
```

---

Removing nodes with DOM is always the same approach. Find the node you want to remove. Get to it's `parentNode` and call `removeChild` on it with the node to be removed as the argument.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('foo') as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

---

You can also navigate to sibling nodes (and child nodes) without XPath. Here is how to remove all following siblings after the first h1 element

```
$firstH1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1')->item(0);
while ($firstH1->nextSibling !== NULL) {
    $firstH1->parentNode->removeChild($firstH1->nextSibling);
}
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Removing nodes from the `DOMDocument`, will affect the `DOMDocument` immediately. In the code above, we are always querying for the first following sibling of the first h1. If there is one, it is removed from the `DOMDocument`. `nextSibling` will then point to the sibling after the one just removed (if any).

---

Fetching and printing all paragraphs is equally easy. To get the outerXML, just pass the node for which you want the outerXML to the `saveXML` method.

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph)
{
    echo $dom->saveXml($paragraph);
}
```

Anyway, that should get you going. I suggest you [familiarize yourself with the DOM API](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). It's not difficult. You will find that most of the things you will do revolve around properties and method in either `DOMDocument`, `DOMNode` and `DOMElement` (which is a subclass of `DOMNode`).

Comment: +1 Good answer. Maybe `/descendant::h1[1]/preceding::p[not(ancestor::table)]` would be faster (not testing all the precedings for each `p`)

Comment: @Alejandro thanks. Yeah, that might be faster. I've added it as an alternative to the answer above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Gordon.

The solution:

```
    $dom = @DOMDocument::loadHTML($xml);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $query = $xpath->query('//p[
        not(ancestor::table) and
        not(preceding::h1[1])
        ]');

    foreach ($query as $node){
        $result .= $dom->saveXml($node);
    }  

    echo $result;
```